# wordpress get_the_post_thumbnail is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello friends i used `get_the_post_thumbnail()` this function like.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail");
```

This is working properly and return the thumbnail images.

But i write like this is not working.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail(55, "thumbnail");
or
get_the_post_thumbnail('55', "thumbnail");
```

This is not return any thing please help. I'm using the `$wpdb->get_results();`

thank you.

Comment: Are you echoing the `get_the_post_thumbnail(55, "thumbnail");`. Because it works here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store `get_the_ID()` value in to variable and then call it.

e.g:

```
$A = 55;
get_the_post_thumbnail($A, "thumbnail");
```

Try this

Comment: Its the same thing Chintan. It will work without setting it as a variable.

Comment: For new version of WP you can not directly pass integer value in functions. you must need to pass through variable.

Comment: Chintan refrence will be helpful.

Comment: It's only a problem because you're using an integer. 1 vs '1'